# jsp anchor link showing wrong url

Tags: java, html, jsp, servlets, anchor

i have two jsp pages

pages/sample.jsp

```
    <html>
   <body>
   <a href="../pages/events.jsp">events</a>
   </body>
   </html>
```

if i click this event link in browser it,s work fine and browser show the url as    localhost:8080/System/pages/events.jsp   here system is my application name . this is ok
but  i have another jsp page as

index.jsp

```
       <html>
        <body>
          <jsp:include page="/pages/sample.jsp" />
       </body>
      </html>
```

when i open this page in browser and click on event link     it shows not found  error and browser show url as  localhost:8080/pages/events.jsp  according to the url my application name  " system " is not mention why?

if i modify  pages/sample.jsp    page as

```
      <html>
   <body>
      <a href="/pages/events.jsp">events</a>
  </body>
   </html>
```

and open index.jsp page in browser it works fine but if i open  pages/sample.jsp   individually  and click on event link  it again show not found error   browser show url like this         localhost:8080/System/pages/pages/events.jsp       here my " pages " folder is mentioned two times why?

Comment: Please question is confusing man please revamp it?

Comment: something happening wrong with anchor link      if  i put <a href="/pageg/sample.jsp">,<a/>   after clicking  it lands on some  url    if  i put <a href="../pageg/sample.jsp"" >,<a/>   it lands on some different  url  if  i  include  this page in an other  page  it again land on some different location

Comment: <a href="../page/sample.jsp> with this

Comment: is sample.jsp and event.jsp at same directory in veiw ?

Comment: i have two  pages  " /pages/sample.jsp" here " pages  "is folder name  where " sample.jsp " located and  "index.jsp"  it is located in root directory